# How to avoid extra rendering in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have next object:

```
Book = {
    id: 1,
    titel: "Some Book",
    sections: [
                {id: 1,
                 titel: "Section Titel",
                 pages: [
                          {id: 1, content: "Some text"},
                          {id: 2, content: "Some text"},
                          {id: 3, content: "Some text"}
                        ]
                },
                {id: 2,
                 titel: "Section Titel",
                 pages: [
                          {id: 1, content: "Some text"},
                          {id: 2, content: "Some text"}
                        ]
                }
              ]
}
```

`Book` object stored in Redux store (`state.Book`).

I have component which visualizes this `Book` object.

Component `Book` renders one or more `Section` components and each `Section` component renders `Page` component.

`Book` subscribed to Redux over `connect` function from react-redux and listens to `store.Book`, hole object.

It is clear that when `titel` of the `Book` will change then hole `Book` object will be re-rendered including all `Sections` and `Pages`.

There are two questions:

1. Will react engine really re-render `Sections` and `Pages` if only `Book.titel` changed? Or it will identify that other parts of the component do not changed and will not re-render them.
2. If it will re-render then what is the best way to avoid it? Should I subscribe `Section` and `Page` component to the `Store` also? But it will not solve the problem, because `Book` listens to hole `state.Book` object. Or should I subscribe `Book` component only to `state.Book.id` and `state.Book.titel`, then use `this.context.store` inside to path data to the inner components?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, React will call the `render` method in `Sections` and `Pages` but don't be worried about performance as those are really inexpensive operations. The Virtual DOM will abstract all the heavy operations (i.e. manipulating the DOM) minimizing the impact on performance. You can run some quick tests yourself to see how the UX is not affected at all by changes this size.
2. I would not recommend to prevent re-rendering (as I said in #1 it's an unexpensive operation) but if you really want to, you could use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `Section` components. You just need to return `false` whenever you feel the `Section` or their child components don't need to render

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. It was very helpful. Actually I think about `shouldComponentUpdate`, but then if react so clever to not update unchanged DOM element then there is not so much use case for it.